# Firestore rules to read documents where specific field exists

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my `users collection`I have a few users where a field is present which is called `startupData` field and now I want to make these documents public. So I am trying to make rules for it but so far no luck.

This is my document with the field.

[image]

These are the rules that i have created so far

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /users/{uid} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/{document=**}).data.startupData
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can also use debug() function to see values into firestore-debug.log file. This is an important function to disclose values of conditions in firebase rules.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the `hasAll` [keyword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#combining_required_and_optional_fields).

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /users/{uid} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
        allow read: if resource.data.keys().hasAll(['startupData'])
    }
  }
```